# How to append new element and hide existing?

Tags: jquery, append, lightbox

I am trying to append '.test' to '#lig' and this works but obviously loads all the elements with the same class. 
How would I have it so that it would hide the existing and only get the '.test' from the same div?

```
<div class="qq">
    <a href="image1.jpg" class="more">More</a>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com" class="test">Yahoo</a>
</div>

<div class="qq">
    <a href="image2.jpg" class="more">More</a>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="test">Google</a>
</div>

<div id="lig"></div>



$('.test').appendTo('#lig');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a class to the currently displayed or selected element?

```
$('.qq').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  //..append to #lig
});
```

Then when u want to grab the same element or (not):

```
$('.selected .test')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#lig .test')
   .hide() // hide existing .test
   .parent() // back to #lig
   .append('.test'); // append .test
```